# How to output the maximum value inside an array

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void value(int array[],int size){
    
    int minimum;
    int maximum;
    
    minimum = array[0];
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        if(minimum > array[x+1]){
        minimum = array[x+1];
    }
    }
    maximum = array[0];
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
        if(maximum < array[x+1]){
        maximum = array[x+1];
    }
    }
    cout << "Minimum Value is: " << minimum << endl;
    cout << "Maximum Value is: " << maximum;
    
}

int main(){
    int size;

    cout << "Number of values you want to input: ";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "Input " << size << " values" << endl;
    
    int array[size];
    
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
    cout << "Input #" << x+1 <<": ";
    cin >> array[x];
    }
    
    value(array,size);
    
    return 0;
```

How can I output the maximum value inside the array? **whenever I print the value the maximum value always return a number that is not present inside the array** but the minimum seems fine, its only the maximum value that I am encountering a problem, I tried every possible answer that I know but it doesn't work, I hope ya'll can help Thank you in advance

Comment: Change your for loops to run up to `size - 1`

Comment: You have undefined behavior in your program.

Comment: BTW, you can do both in one loop.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element. Doesn't seem to work with VLA, though. But VLAs are not standard C++.

Comment: In `value` change your for loop to start at 1 and don't use `x+1` as this makes it harder to reason about the array loops. In fact you messed that up because for `x = size - 1` the `x + 1 == size` is out of bounds of the array. Next forget about C arrays and use std::vector (or std::array for fixed sized arrays). Is c++11 a requirement? Later standards have more things to make this simpler.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
```

If you have an array with ten values, `size` will be 10. If you work out, with paper and pencil, what this `for` loop does, you will see that it iterates for values of `x` 0 through 9, that's what this says. `x` starts with 0. When it reaches 10, `x < size` will be false and the loop ends, so the loop runs with `x` ranging from 0 to 9.

```
        if(minimum > array[x+1]){
```

Since `x` will range from 0-9, it logically follows that `x+1` will range from 1 to 10, and so this `if` statement will check the values in `array[1]` through `array[10]`.

In C++ array indexes start with 0, not 1. The values in your array are `array[0]` through `array[9]`. `array[10]` does not exist, so the above code is undefined behavior.

Furthermore:

```
int array[size];
```

This is not valid C++ either. Your C++ compiler may allow this as a non-standard C++ extension, but array sizes must be fixed, constant sizes in C++, determined at ***compile time***. You can't use a non-constant variable to set the size of an array, C++ does not work this way. If you need to have an array of size that's determined at runtime then you need to use `std::vector` instead of a plain array, and change the rest of your code accordingly.

Comment: No, they are initialized. Look again.

Comment: Correct, sorry, missed those lines

Answer (score -1):

##### Mistake 1

Your example has **undefined behavior** because of the expression `array[x+1]`. That is, for the last iteration of the `for` loop, you're going **out of bounds** of the array and so have undefined behavior.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

##### Mistake 2

In standard C++, the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**. So in your code:

```
int size;
cin >> size;
int array[size]; //NOT STANDARD C++
```

The statement `int array[size];` is not standard C++ because `size` is not a **constant expression**.

**Additionally** you don't need 2 separate `for` loops when you can achieve the goal in 1 `for` loop as shown below.

##### Solution 1

You can use `std::vector` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>
 
//this function take a vector as input 
void value(const std::vector<int>& arr)
{    
  int max_num = INT_MIN;
  int min_num = INT_MAX;
  
  //iterate through the vector to find the max and min value 
  for(const int& element: arr)
  {
      if(element >  max_num)
      {
          max_num = element;
      }
      if(element < min_num)
      {
          min_num = element;
      }
  }
  std::cout<<"maximum is: "<<max_num<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"minimum is: "<<min_num; //return the difference of mx and min value
}
 

int main()
{
  int n;
  std::cout<<"elements: ";
  std::cin >> n;

  //create vector of int of size n 
  std::vector<int>  arr(n);
  
  //take elements from user
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
    std::cin >> arr[i];
  }
  
  value(arr);
 
  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/4WSpsi8z5)

##### Solution 2

You can make the function a **function template** so that you don't need to pass a separate argument to the function as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
//N is a nontype template parameter
template<std::size_t N> 
void value(const int (&array)[N]){
    
    int max_num = INT_MIN;
    int min_num = INT_MAX;
  
  //iterate through the array to find the max and min value 
  for(const int& element: array)
  {
      if(element >  max_num)
      {
          max_num = element;
      }
      if(element < min_num)
      {
          min_num = element;
      }
  }
  std::cout<<"maximum is: "<<max_num<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"minimum is: "<<min_num;
}

int main(){
    int array[3] = {};
    
    for(int x = 0; x < sizeof (array) / (sizeof (array[0])); x++){
        std::cout << "Input #" << x+1 <<": ";
        std::cin >> array[x];
    }
    
    value(array); //no need to pass the second argument
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/-89F-8h6m)

---

Also note that with C++17, you can use `std::size` instead of `sizeof (array) / (sizeof (array[0]))` to find the length of the array.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: Stop teaching (bad) C. This clearly calls for std::vector.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow First i have already added `std::vector` solution in my answer. Second, using templates is  not at all bad. Don't you know `std::vector` is a template itself? Third, don't be so judgemental when i have mentioned both the solutions.

Comment: @AnnopRana I have no beef with the template. But why not use std::array for that instead of C style array? Just that change and using `at()` would have turned the UB into an exception. Much easier to find the error for a beginner (and expert imho). I still think std::vector is the better solution but that is an opinion.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Ok so you should've specified that you think i should have used `std::array`. My point is that i was working on the `std::vector` solution when you wrote you first comment, and just after 30-40 seconds i added the `std::vector` solution in my answer. Ofcourse you(or anyone) could not have predicted that i was working on `std::vector` solution. I agree that `std::vector` is the way to go. Also, yes `std::array` can be used and `.at()` can also be used. But since i already have 2 solutions in the answer i don't think i want to add a third solution.

Comment: Continued... Note that the 2nd solution that uses `array` instead of `vector` or `std::array` is there so that the OP can see what changes he/she has to made to his/her current program to make the program techincally correct. It(the 2nd solution) is not intended as the best solution.

Comment: Thanks Anoop. No harm was mend. The vector example is perfect. Uses c++11 feature to make it easy to read and safe while retaining the original algorithm of doing this by hand.